# ifconfig segfault - RHEL6

Tags: linux, ld, rhel6

```
[root@obiee01 log]# ifconfig
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Excerpt from /var/log/messages

```
Server is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6

Feb 10 15:11:24 obiee01 kernel: ifconfig[3000]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f983a0a3453 sp 00007ffffe7c8a90 error 4 in ld-2.12.so[7f983a098000+20000]
Feb 10 15:11:24 obiee01 abrt[3001]: Not saving repeating crash in '/sbin/ifconfig'
Feb 10 15:11:34 obiee01 abrtd: New problem directory /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2015-02-10-15:11:12-2782, processing
Feb 10 15:11:34 obiee01 abrtd: Sending an email...
Feb 10 15:11:34 obiee01 abrtd: Email was sent to: root@localhost
```

Comment: This is, quite clearly, not a programming question and hence off-topic.

Comment: If you have RHEL, you almost certainly have a support contract for it, in which case RH sould be falling over themselves trying to help you out.